# Why is environment variable mangled in docker compose environment file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Context: docker-compose to start several containers, including Gunicorn that calls a Flask app. I'm using an environment file `web/env.gunicorn` to store my Gunicorn startup configuration. This file contains

```
GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--bind=127.0.0.1:8001 --workers=3"
```

The problem is that `GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS` is not processed correctly somewhere in the pipeline. The error that I get when running `docker logs gunicorn` is

```
Error: '8001 --workers=3' is not a valid port number.
```

The question is, where in my setup are my assumptions wrong, thereby causing the environment variable to be mangled? The environment variable is accepted when run manually in a terminal. The docker compose file looks as follows

```
version: "3"
services:
#  nginx:
#    image: nginx:latest
#    ports:
#      - "80:80"
#    volumes:
#      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
#    depends_on:
#      - web

  web:
    build: ./web
    container_name: gunicorn
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    environment:
      - APP_CONFIG_FILE=../config/development.py
    env_file:
      - 'web/env.gunicorn'
    networks:
      - backend
    command: gunicorn thymedata:app
    depends_on:
      - influxdb
      - grafana

  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:latest
    container_name: influxdb
    ports:
      - "8086:8086"
    env_file:
      - 'influxdb/env.influxdb'
      - 'influxdb/secrets.influxdb'
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - influxdb-data:/var/lib/influxdb

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    container_name: grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    env_file:
      - 'grafana/env.grafana'
      - 'grafana/secrets.grafana'
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - grafana-data:/var/lib/grafana
    depends_on:
      - influxdb

networks:
  backend:

volumes:
  influxdb-data:
  grafana-data:
```

Comment: Not using gunicorn, but reading the doc there's no = sign out of the note at about the env variable. I'd try with a space, but it sounds like it doesn't parse properly multiples arguments and as such is maybe a bug in gunicorn (inverting the arguments order to end by the bind argument may be a workaround or exhibit the split problem with the workers parameter)

Comment: I tried changing the ordering of the parameters, but that did not help. I also tried starting Gunicorn from the command line with `GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS` set, and it accepted it properly (# of workers and address checked). That's why i suppose the problem being on Docker's side.

Comment: `ERROR: build path /home/ben/devopsStackExchange/web either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL.`. Please create a `steps to reproduce paragraph` and add the required files so that other people could help you by at least allowing them to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please add at least the Gunicorn Dockerfile.

Comment: I don't use a Gunicorn Dockerfile. I'll stick to the `command: gunicorn thymedata:app --bind=127.0.0.1:8001 --workers=3` version, since the variables loaded via `env_file` are not accepted. They have to already be set in the calling terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading [the commands chapter](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html#commands) and finding [this sample](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1533), it looks like that the custom `GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS` could be omitted by just passing the arguments directly:

```
command: gunicorn thymedata:app --bind=127.0.0.1:8001 --workers=3
```

If one really would like to use variables then it could be done as follows:

```
command: gunicorn thymedata:app --bind=${GUNICORN_BIND_ADDRESS} --workers=${GUNICORN_WORKERS}
```

.env

```
GUNICORN_BIND_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1:8001
GUNICORN_WORKERS=3
```

Comment: ${GUNICORN_BIND_ADDRESS} will only evaluate variables already in the terminal, none that are loaded via `env_file`. Since I do not set any secrets, it's an acceptable solution

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and this worked for me without it feeling like a hack...

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3'
services:
   web:
      build .
      environment:
      - GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS=--workers=0 --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout=10
```

*Note: add env GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS without quotes*

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
ENV GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --workers=3"
CMD gunicorn app:app
```

*Note: run CMD gunicorn app:app without passing options via array or quotes*

Answer (score 0):

In ran into this problem with my environment file with docker-compose, and I found the problem to be with the quotes.

If I put `GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS=--bind=127.0.0.1:8001 --workers=3` on the .env file the parameters are accepted without any issue, but if I put quotes around them the variable gets mangled by docker-compose.